# What does random.Random (not random.random) from the random module actually do in Python?

Tags: python, random

I would like to get a lucid explanation on what the random.Random function/class actually does. This is what Python's random module has to say about it.

> Random number generator base class used by bound module functions.
>   Used to instantiate instances of Random to get generators that don't
>   share state.  Especially useful for multi-threaded programs, creating
>   a different instance of Random for each thread, and using the
>   jumpahead() method to ensure that the generated sequences seen by each
>   thread don't overlap.
>
> Class Random can also be subclassed if you want to use a different
>   basic generator of your own devising: in that case, override the
>   following methods: random(), seed(), getstate(), setstate() and
>   jumpahead(). Optionally, implement a getrandbits() method so that
>   randrange() can cover arbitrarily large ranges.

I do not understand this because I am still very much a beginner at Python. I do know a bit about base and derived classes and this clearly seems to have something to do with this.

I tried to play around with the random.Random() function/class in Python's IDLE and found out the following.

- It only seems to accept 1 argument.(string, int, float)
- Doesn't seem to to take in any lists or dictionaries as an argument; states they are unhashable. (What does 'unhashable' mean?)
- It only seems to return two values alternatively on repeatedly invoking it, regardless of the argument passed to it, the two values being 'random.Random object at 0x03F24E40' and 'random.Random object at 0x03F26B60'.

I hope I can get a simple explanation of what random.Random does and also an explanation as to why it only returns two values. (I am a beginner so forgive my ignorance on the subject!)

Any explanation on how functions like seed(), getstate(), setstate() and jumpahead() work or references to any documents/books that explain so are welcome.

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/random.py#L71

Comment: All other functions in random module `seed`, `randint` etc. are defined inside this class. They all share the same seed value, gauss value and hence, you only have to do `random.seed` once.

Comment: What about the documentation of [random.random()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.random) is not lucid enough ? >Return the next random floating point number in the range [0.0, 1.0)

Comment: I am sorry, I think you misunderstood my question @reportgunner. I am referring to random.Random() and not random.random().

Comment: also try `help(random.Random)` if you imported by saying `import random` in IDLE

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @reportgunner. I tried that, but no luck. It just states the same thing that I mentioned within blockquotes in the explanation for the question (which I am inept at understanding).

Comment: @Prosopon yes but it also lists all the methods and their comments. It is still not clear what you are looking for exactly and what the result is supposed to be.

Comment: @reportgunner, Okay, maybe you are right. I should probably read up a little more on the nuances of the random module and then I'll get it. I'll still probably have to figure out why random.Random() module returns the two values I mentioned in the question's explanation alternatively and what they exactly mean. In that case, I may consider editing the question.

Comment: that is just because it returns the `next` random generator. if you store at least one of them in a variable you will get a third value and so on.  
>>> a = random.Random()
>>> b = random.Random()
>>> c = random.Random()
>>> a,b,c
(<random.Random object at 0x00000000028E2788>, <random.Random object at 0x00000000028F33E8>, <random.Random object at 0x00000000028F3DF8>)

Comment: Thanks @reportgunner. That comment was helpful :). I think I get it. I'll check that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple terms, `random.Random()` creates a pseudorandom number generator, that is, an object that generates a sequence of numbers that appear random (are *pseudorandom*).

`random.Random()` accepts one object that can be a 'string', 'int' (integer), or 'float' (integer or non-integer such as 3.2 or 888). This object is called a *seed*, and it can be used to create an object that generates a specific sequence of pseudorandom numbers. For example, you can call—

- `random.Random(57)`,
- `random.Random(888.6)`,
- `random.Random("Hello World")`, or
- `random.Random(99898989)`,

to get a generator of a specific sequence of pseudorandom numbers. However, you should specify a *seed* only if you need repeatable "randomness" in your program.

You can then use this generator to extract pseudorandom numbers from that sequence:

```
# Create a generator without
# a seed, so that the pseudorandom
# sequence will almost surely differ
# from run to run
randomGen = random.Random()
# Generate a number in [0, 1)
number = randomGen.random()
# Generate an integer in [0, 5]
number = randomGen.randint(0, 5)
```

Note that the example assigns the generator from `random.Random` to a variable named `randomGen`; in general, it's not useful on its own simply to create a generator.